# Customize the string spliting in terms of a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's a brief example of a reference list from my huge dataframe.

```
reference = ['I am not sure', "I don't know who to talk to", 'No', 'Not listed (specify)', 'I do not feel comfortable answering this question','Not really describing my situation']
```

And I need to transform a bunch of strings such as `"I don't know who to talk to, Not listed (specify)"` into `'2 4'`

###### Here's how I tried

```
answer = "I don't know who to talk to, Not listed (specify)"

res = ''
for idx, choice in enumerate(reference, 1):
    if choice in answer:
        res += str(idx) + " "
print(res[:-1])

>>> '2 3 4'
```

The problem is, there're some overlapping text in the choices in the `reference` and I can't simply call `split(',')` since there're complicated punctuations in other `reference` lists. Can somebody help me try something other than regex?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Don't you expect `2 4` instead of `2 3`?

Comment: @Tranbi My mistake, u r right

Comment: How big is the reference list?

Comment: One way that may help is to sort reference list and use Python's bisect module (or convert to a pandas series and use method "searchsorted"). Search for the insertion point of "answer" (left side) should return the index of the longest string in "reference" which is the beginning of "answer". You can then remove this part from answer, also remove punctuation until next word and repeat search. This may not work for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be pretty (going a lot through `reference` efficiency will be terrible when the list grows) but might do what you want:

```
from itertools import combinations
reference = ['I am not sure', "I don't know who to talk to", 'No', 'Not listed (specify)', 'I do not feel comfortable answering this question','Not really describing my situation']
answer = "I don't know who to talk to, Not listed (specify)"

ref_count = dict(zip(reference, [0]*len(reference)))    # initializing counter

# first counting occurences of reference elements in answer
for key in reference:
    if key in answer:
        ref_count[key] += 1

# decreasing counter when longer element containing shorter one is found in string
for key1, key2 in combinations(reference, 2):
    if key1 in key2 and ref_count[key2] > 0:
        ref_count[key1] -= 1

print(' '.join([str(idx) for idx, x in enumerate(reference, 1) if ref_count[x] > 0]))
```

EDIT: replacing double loop with single loop over `combinations`